# Sorting rows before joining one table to multiple tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables: question and answer.

Here is a simplified version of the **question** table's schema:

```
question_id      integer PRIMARY KEY
question_title   varchar(250)
answers_id       SERIAL UNIQUE
```

Here is a simplified version of the **answer** table's schema:

```
answer_id        integer REFERENCES question (answers_id)
answer_text      varchar(500)
is_top_answer    boolean
```

I would like to accomplish three tasks in a single query:

1. Select a row from the question table based off of a parameter that contains a question_id.
2. Join **exactly one** row from the answer table with the row retrieved from the question's table in step 1 of the query where the two following conditions are satisfied by a row in the answer table: 1. the is_top_answer is true and 2. the answer_id equals the answers_id of the row retrieved from the question table in step 1 of the query.
3. Join a **variable amount** of rows from the answer table with the row retrieved from the question's table in step 1 of the query where the answer table's answer_id matches the answers_id of the row retrieved from the question table in step 1 of the query.

I have populated the question and answer tables with the following SQL statements:

```
insert into question values (1, 'Where is the best sushi restaurant?', 10);
insert into answer values (10, 'In California', 'false');
insert into answer values (10, 'In Seattle', 'true');
insert into answer values (10, 'In New York', 'false');
```

If I were to query the question table with a parameter that represents a question_id held in the question table, I would expect the following row as a result:

```
 question_id |           question_title            | answers_id |   answer_text | is_top_answer  |   answer_text | is_top_answer  |   answer_text | is_top_answer  |
-------------+-------------------------------------+------------+---------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+
           1 | Where is the best sushi restaurant? |         10 | In Seattle    | f              | In California | f              | In New York   | f              |
```

I have tried to use a subquery SELECT statement, which attempts to satisfy tasks 2 and 3 of the query by returning all the row from the answer table where answer_id matches the answers_id of the question table's row ordered by ascending values of the is_top_answer, within a LEFT JOIN statement, but I have not had success because the postgres complains with a "subquery must return only one column" error. Here is the query:

```
    SELECT (q.question_id, q.question_title), 
        (SELECT answer_id, answer_text FROM answer 
            WHERE answer_id = q.answers_id 
            ORDER BY is_top_answer ASC) 
    FROM question q 
    RIGHT JOIN answer a ON a.answer_id = q.answers_id 
    WHERE q.question_id = $1
```

I have also tried this query:

```
    select * from question inner join answer on question.answers_id = answer.answer_id 
    where question.question_id = 1 
    order by answer.is_top_answer;
```

The result of this query is three rows:

```
 question_id |           question_title            | answers_id | answer_id |  answer_text  | is_top_answer 
-------------+-------------------------------------+------------+-----------+---------------+---------------
           1 | Where is the best sushi restaurant? |         10 |        10 | In California | f
           1 | Where is the best sushi restaurant? |         10 |        10 | In New York   | f
           1 | Where is the best sushi restaurant? |         10 |        10 | In Seattle    | t
```

Each row has a copy of a row from the question and answer tables. I am not looking for three rows, I am trying to create a query that returns one row that is a combination of one row from the question table and multiple rows from the answer table.

Any advice about accomplishing the three tasks in a single query would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  I (for one) find it hard to following your rules.  Also, decide if you are using MySQL or Postgres and tag the question appropriately.

Comment: with step 3 you want to get all the answers for the question (top an not) and with step 2 you want only the top answer? thats what i understand

Comment: @Skaros Ilias  Yes, that is exactly right.

Comment: so, you need all the answers AND the top answer

Comment: Yes, in that specific order. I want to join the top answer first and then I want join all the other answers that have the same answer_id as the answers_id of the row queried from the question table.

Answer (score 0):

does this work? (havent tested it)

```
select * from question inner join answer on 
    questions.answers_id=answer.answer_id where question.question_id = $1
```

this will bring all of the answers. you can not get both all the ansers and the best answers. it makes no sence. if you get all of them you will get the best answer as well. maybe you can do

```
select * from question inner join answer on 
    questions.answers_id=answer.answer_id where question.question_id = $1
    order by asnwer.is_top_answer
```

in order to get the top answer first on the list

Comment: Thanks for the help. The query does run without errors, but it does not return the proper results. The query returns a copy of the question with every single answer that has a matching answers_id. I am trying to create a query that returns a row that is composed of one row from the question table and several rows from the answer table.

Comment: edit your question with an example of what you want to get, and maybe what this code gave you

Comment: llias, sorry for the confusion. I have made the requested edits.

Answer (score 0):

If you want one row, then use aggregation:

```
select q.*,
       string_agg(answer_text, '|' order by is_top_answer desc) as answers
from question q inner join
     answer a 
     on q.answers_id = a.answer_id
where q.question_id = $1;
```

The data structure in your question seems messed up.  Normally, each question would have a unique auto-incremented primary key called `question_id`.  Each answer would have a unique auto-incremented primary key called `answer_id`.  Each answer would also have a link back to the question via a field called `question_id`.  However, this answer follows the naming conventions in the question.

Comment: You are right, the answers_id in the questions table is completely unnecessary. I will get rid of the answers_id in the questions table, and I will define a reference to the question_id in the answer table's answer_id.