# Combining a variable amount of rows into one row?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have two tables: question and answer.

Here is a simplified version of the **question** table's schema:

```
question_id      integer PRIMARY KEY
question_title   varchar(250)
answers_id       SERIAL UNIQUE
```

Here is a simplified version of the **answer** table's schema:

```
answer_id        integer REFERENCES question (answers_id)
answer_text      varchar(500)
is_top_answer    boolean
```

I would like to accomplish three tasks in a single query:

1. Select a row from the question table based off of a parameter that contains a question_id.
2. Join **exactly one** row from the answer table with the row retrieved from the question's table in step 1 of the query where the two following conditions are satisfied by a row in the answer table: 1. the is_top_answer is true and 2. the answer_id equals the answers_id of the row retrieved from the question table in step 1 of the query.
3. Join a **variable amount** of rows from the answer table with the row retrieved from the question's table in step 1 of the query where the answer table's answer_id matches the answers_id of the row retrieved from the question table in step 1 of the query.

I have populated the question and answer tables with the following SQL statements:

```
insert into question values (1, 'Where is the best sushi restaurant?', 10);
insert into answer values (10, 'In California', 'false');
insert into answer values (10, 'In Seattle', 'true');
insert into answer values (10, 'In New York', 'false');
```

If I were to query the question table with a parameter that represents a question_id held in the question table, I would expect the following single row as a result:

```
 question_id |           question_title            | answers_id |   answer_text | is_top_answer  |   answer_text | is_top_answer  |   answer_text | is_top_answer  |
-------------+-------------------------------------+------------+---------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+
           1 | Where is the best sushi restaurant? |         10 | In Seattle    | f              | In California | f              | In New York   | f              |
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for accomplishing this query?

Comment: `SERIAL` sort of screams Postgres.  Why is the question tagged MySQL?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Because I didn't get much assistance when I posted with a postgre tag.

Comment: Isn't that the same question as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30694777/sorting-rows-before-joining-one-table-to-multiple-tables (and it's postgres, not postgre)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM question 
INNER JOIN answer on question.answers_id = answer.answer_id
WHERE question_id = 1
```

This the basic query that you need. After that you have to use [crosstab](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/tablefunc.html), but since you have unlimited number of answer rows its very difficult. The method in detailed on this SO post [Dynamic alternative to pivot with CASE and GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506199/dynamic-alternative-to-pivot-with-case-and-group-by/15514334#15514334).

Another method is to use [array_agg](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-aggregate.html) function, but the result wont be the same as the you need

```
SELECT 
    question_id, array_agg(question_title) AS 'questionlist', array_agg(answers_id || '##' || answer_text || '##' || is_top_answer) AS 'answerlist'
FROM question 
INNER JOIN answer on question.answers_id = answer.answer_id
WHERE question_id = 1  
GROUP BY question_id
```

After that you have to split the `questionlist` and `answerlist` in the server side code